# ggplot x axis different from database

Tags: r, ggplot2

When i was trying to plot a line, the x-axis came out different from the database. This is my data:

```
 Month num temp
1   2016-1-1     61  4.5
2   2016-2-1     50  3.8
3   2016-3-1     51  5.3
4   2016-4-1     48  6.5
5   2016-5-1     49 11.3
6   2016-6-1     48 13.9
7   2016-7-1     50 15.3
8   2016-8-1     48 15.5
9   2016-9-1     52 14.6
10 2016-10-1     54  9.8
11 2016-11-1     69  4.9
12 2016-12-1     80  5.9
13  2017-1-1     59  3.8
14  2017-2-1     52  5.2
15  2017-3-1     51  7.3
16  2017-4-1     47  8.0
17  2017-5-1     50 12.1
18  2017-6-1     47 14.4
```

and my code was:

```
ggplot(data=trendsData,aes(x=Month, y=temp,group=1))+geom_line()+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = .5))
```

but it came out:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9EXy.png)

Could anyone help with the disorder, thanks!

Comment: How do you want horizontal axis to be plot? Does it need to have the current format of yyyy-mm-dd?

Answer (score 0):

R can only sort those dates correctly when it knows what they are infact dates.

`ymd()` from the package lubridate is nice for that.

```
trendsData$Month <- ymd( trendsData$Month )
```

Then your plot should be fine.

EDIT:

If you want more date points to show on the x axis, you can use `scale_x_date()` like so:

```
+ scale_x_date( breaks=trendsData$Month )
```